# How to set list view with array?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

i've problem setting the list view, 
When i create the array and i try to put into the list view, return error Cannot resolve constructor ArrayAdapter
this is my array.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.xml_busqueda_proveedores);


ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arl = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("lista");

System.out.println("::: array " + arl); 
// This is the array
// ::: array [{1=111, 2= LOCAL }, {1=12, 2= CIUDAD}, {}, {}, {}]

list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListProveedores);

ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arl);
//Error Cannot resolve constructor ArrayAdapter
list.setAdapter(adaptador);
}
```

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> is useful only when you are using Simple Array or ArrayList. You are using ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>.. So you need to use Custom Adapter. go with this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701943/how-to-use-insert-data-from-arraylisthashmapstring-string-into-a-list-view

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because you create an ArrayAdapter of String but you give to your adapter an ArrayList of HashMap of two strings.